# Fastai (Image Transformation) n_out is not defined

Tags: python, pytorch, runtime-error, nameerror, fast-ai

I am very new to this. I was trying build image transformation network that turns rgb image into depth image (which is just normal image). And I keep having n_out is not defined issue.

> `n_out` is not defined, and could not be inferred from data, set `dls.c` or pass `n_out`.

My code:

```
nyu = DataBlock(blocks=(ImageBlock, ImageBlock),
                       get_items=get_rgb_files,
                       get_y=lambda x: str(x).replace(".jpg", ".png"),
                      
                       item_tfms=Resize(256),
                       batch_tfms=[*aug_transforms()], 
                    
                     )
```

```
learn = vision_learner(dls, resnet34, loss_func=nn.MSELoss)
```

And if I try

```
learn = vision_learner(dls, resnet34, loss_func=nn.MSELoss, n_out=1)
```

I get

> `RuntimeError: Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous`

I was trying create image from target image. I just want to figure out general workflow of it so I can work things out.If you can tell me what is my problem I'll be very grateful.